# Why is this showing 'Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration'

Tags: swift, class

I'm new to coding and using SwiftUI on Xcode, and I don't see what's wrong with this code:

```
class NormalSpace {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0
    var rent = 0
    var owned = false
}

var newRoad = NormalSpace()

newRoad.name = "New Road"
newRoad.value = 600
newRoad.rent = 25
newRoad.owned = false
```

the error 'Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration' only shows on the newRoad.name line. The same line also has the error: Invalid redeclaration of 'newRoad'.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where is this class declared? Inside other class or in a new seperate file?

Comment: It’s in its own file

Comment: Then you can't assign value to properties openly. They should be part of a struct/class and inside a method (func).

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's by itself in a in a struct. So it still needs to be in a func?

Comment: Yes, you can't have code like that at the top level of struct or class. And perhaps also not a class declared inside a struct although it is technically allowed.

Comment: Inside a `struct` you can declare variables, constants and functions, but you can't run code that is "hanging" inside. What's hanging inside a `struct` or `class` is created all at once, but if you have code that needs to run in sequence, you must use a function/ initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an normal project, this is not valid:

```
class NormalSpace {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0
    var rent = 0
    var owned = false
}

var newRoad = NormalSpace()

newRoad.name = "New Road"
newRoad.value = 600
newRoad.rent = 25
newRoad.owned = false
```

You can do that in a playground (where it just runs this code directly), but in an app, code (such as the setting of the properties) belongs in a function or initializer.

That initialization code needs to be placed within some context. Let us imagine that it is inside a `struct`. But this still is not valid:

```swift
class NormalSpace {
    var name = ""
    var value = 0
    var rent = 0
    var owned = false
}

struct Foo {
    var newRoad = NormalSpace()
    
    newRoad.name = "New Road"
    newRoad.value = 600
    newRoad.rent = 25
    newRoad.owned = false
}
```

The property, `newRoad` is fine, but the values are not. You need to wrap it inside a `func` (hence the error) or an `init`. E.g., this initializes `newRoad` during the `init` of the `struct`:

```swift
struct Foo {
    let newRoad: NormalSpace
    
    init() {
        newRoad = NormalSpace()

        newRoad.name = "New Road"
        newRoad.value = 600
        newRoad.rent = 25
        newRoad.owned = false
    }
}
```

Or you might initialize it in a `func`:

```swift
struct Foo {
    var newRoad: NormalSpace?

    mutating func bar() {
        let road = NormalSpace()

        road.name = "New Road"
        road.value = 600
        road.rent = 25
        road.owned = false

        newRoad = road
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can initialize this property with a closure (note the extra `()` at the end):

```swift
struct Foo {
    let newRoad: NormalSpace = {
        let road = NormalSpace()
        road.name = "New Road"
        road.value = 600
        road.rent = 25
        road.owned = false
        return road
    }()
}
```

But the code where you initialize the properties must be placed within some context, so that the compiler knows when those lines of code should be run.

---

Note, we would generally give `NormalSpace` a “memberwise initializer”, e.g.:

```swift
class NormalSpace {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let rent: Int
    let owned: Bool

    init(name: String, value: Int, rent: Int, owned: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.rent = rent
        self.owned = owned
    }
}
```

Or, if a `struct` (and we would generally prefer to make our model objects `struct` value-types rather than `class` reference-types), this memberwise initializer would be created for you:

```swift
struct NormalSpace {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let rent: Int
    let owned: Bool
}
```

Either way, you can then provide all the desired values during initialization, e.g.:

```swift
struct Foo {
    let newRoad = NormalSpace(name: "New Road", value: 600, rent: 25, owned: false)
}
```

Note, that I've removed the “default” values because those really are not appropriate. If you wanted to say that they do not need to be provided, then you would make them “optionals”. But there is generally a big difference between, say, a rent of zero (i.e. it is my grandmother’s house and she's not charging me) and that no rent has been specified. In Swift, we generally avoid using “sentinel” values like `""` or `0` for “no value provided”.

Also, now that we have a memberwise initializer, I have also made the properties immutable (`let` rather than `var`). If you need to make them mutable (e.g. to let someone change the rent later), fine, revert back to `var`. But only make properties mutable if you really need to change them later on.

Comment: Thanks Rob. So if I want to create say 20 different NormalSpace instances (I'm not 100% on the terminology), the last option would be best? And then to reference it in another struct, it would be Foo.newRoad.owned = false, or something along those lines?

Comment: So, I'd certainly go for that “memberwise initialization” pattern. So the question is what is the “model” the the app: Sounds like it would be an array of `NormalSpace` instances, on the basis of your description...

Comment: Basically think Monopoly. A 'player' moves through the `NormalSpace` instances, and buys or pays rent. The plan is to use a `struct` to initialise all the different instances, and then another `struct` to retrieve values like `newRoad.rent`, and use them to change the amount of money of the players or whether the `NormalSpace` is owned.

Comment: I really don’t get the idea behind “one struct to initialize the instances; another to retrieve/change the properties” idea, but you can do whatever you want. But at least you now see how initialization works…